# Jqplot "failed chart" option?

Tags: jqplot

I am using jqplot and for the life of me I can't get it to work on IE8 or IE7. Nevermind I would be happy for it to just work on IE9, Firefox Etc, but I need a message to be displayed if the chart is not successful.

I tried placing a message in the div tags of the chart div, but the problem is that the contents of the div remain even if the chart is rendered.

So is there a way to handle an event of the chart successfully being displayed on which I can write code to hide the message asking them to upgrade their browser?

Comment: ... and yes I've tried all many of variations of JQuery versions and excanvas etc. I've just decided to give up on the hacky world of getting jqplot to work on <IE9 :-)

Comment: I have a pretty complex implementation of jqPlot working on IE7 and IE8.  Any chance you can do a fiddle of where it's not working?  For your inclusion of excanvas, you're doing something like the following?  

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/shared/js/jqPlot/excanvas.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

Comment: @PriorityMark Yes I am doing <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="/shared/js/jqPlot/excanvas.js"></script> <![endif]-->. What if I send you a link to the site with a username and password so you can see it?

Comment: Sure, send me a link, and I'll take a look.

For starters, have you turned on error handling?  If you want it to swallow rendering errors (and not through a js exception) you can just enable catchErrors ($.jqplot.config.catchErrors = true;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is late and everything but I do not like unanswered questions :)

To solve this one I would use a simply wrap of `try catch` around the plot painting method.

[This I am presenting in the following jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/ZrucU/)

Tested on IE7, IE8 and IE9 and only for 9 it does not display an alert suggesting a browser update.

The second option that I could think of is to have a div displaying the update suggestion at start then if the plot is created successfully use the `postDrawHooks` to remove the div. The method use sample:

```
$.jqplot.postDrawHooks.push(function(){
   //code removing the div goes here
});
```